# What is non-collinear magnetism?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, material-science, computational-physics, ferromagnetism

I've just started learning about non-collinear magnetism and heusler alloys and I am finding it hard to understand the concept of non collinear magnetism. I have found few papers on it but most of them describes non collinear magnetism using group theory. Is there any way I can slightly understand the topic without the mathematics?

Comment: I would suggest you try to find a good book on group theory for crystallography instead. The point of group theory is to reduce complexity of the problem, but in a strange way. I always think that it makes job of an experimenter easier because one can use group theory to reduce the number of things you need to measure. [Tinkham's](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Group_Theory_and_Quantum_Mechanics.html?id=oe7DAgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) book is pretty good IMHO

Comment: Also, a more pragmatic point of view. Imagine you managed to understand all you need without group theory. This will not get you too far if everyone in your field uses group theory to support their discussion. You will be speaking your own language that no-one else will understand. Is this a good place to end in?

Comment: Final remark you may not need as much group theory as you think. Sometimes people say SO(3) symmetry instead of spherical symmetry and use none of the accompanying machinery of Lie algebras. So don't run away from it - learn as much as you want/need to proceed

Comment: Thank you for your answer and book recommendation.